# Images Are Not Showing After Hosting @IIS?

Tags: iis-7

I have a ASP.NET MVC site and it works just fine when I run it locally. 
Once I host that site to IIS 7,images are not showing when i browsed
like this "localhost/WebTest/Start/login",but,if i add slash "/" behind of 
these address.it's shown.My image path is "WebTest\Start\Content\test.jpg".
how i fix this problem?i already post this question.i can't get right answer
till now.help me please.

Regards

Chong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have added absolute path to your images.Hence they show up on your local machine and not on the server

Read [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm) and [this](http://support.internetconnection.net/TECHNICAL_REFERENCE/THE_WWW/Absolute_and_Relative_File_Paths.shtml) for an understanding on the same